# Appending Items by Iterating list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I've designed a following function that takes a list as a parameter and returns another list.

```
def function(list):
    A = []
    B = []
    for num in list:
        A.append(num)
        B.append(A)
    return B
```

In this function, I assumed that the function would append A to A depending on the current state of A. Working under that assumption. I called the function

```
>>> test([1,2,3,4,5])
```

expected the output to be

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

However, the result that I get is

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Why is this? Is there any solution around this problem?

Comment: what you are doing is passing by reference the address of A instead of the A's value contents at the moment. hence finally it shows the repeated contents of A instead of showing the value when they were stored.
basic pythonic way to do it.. is as suggested/answered by @Paul Lo. 
and no this is not a problem but a basic python "property"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the copy of `A` to `B` to avoid using the same reference of `A`:

```
for num in list:
      A.append(num)
      B.append(A[:])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy it by value. In your current situation, you are passing by reference. Hence, every index gets updated as `A` changes. Should be:

```
    B.append(A[:])
```

Notice the `[:]` for copying by value.

To clarify, [running your code here](http://pythontutor.com/) we can examine the result of calling `function` on `[1,2]`:

[image: Zalgo the pony is watching.]

Now, consider what happens when we make a copy:

```
def function(list):
    A = []
    B = []
    for num in list:
        A.append(num)
        B.append(A[:])
    return B

print function([1,2])
```

[image: 3 copies, to rule them all.]

Also, as a side note: you should change the names of your variables. For example, by declaring the parameter as `list` you shadow the `list` method.

Comment: What a nice and detailed tutorial within a short time!

Comment: @PaulLo: Thanks. :) But most of the credit should go to the guys who made the nice program that made it easy to visualize these pictures! (www.pythontutor.com)

Answer (score 2):

Lists are passed by reference. To copy them use the syntax `B.append(A[:])`

```
def function(list):
    A = []
    B = []
    for num in list:
        A.append(num)
        B.append(A[:])
    return B
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you sending reference instead of data.

Working  code

```
def function(list):
   A = []
   B = []
   for num in list:
      A.append(num)
      B.append(A[:])
   return B
```